# change pointer with text on hover over text

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, events

In Html if we need to display text on hover over the text what should be the Css for it.
Here is the task that needs to be done is similar to the given image.
[Sample of task that needs to be done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ojDT.png)

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header [collapsedHeight]="'40px'" [expandedHeight]="'40px'"
                                style="margin-left: 50px;border-bottom: 1px solid #4c4c4c;">
                                <mat-panel-title
                                    style="text-decoration: none;color: #FFFFFF;font-size: 15px;font-family: sans-serif;font-weight: 700;width: 209px;overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis; word-break: break-all;white-space: nowrap;"
                                    >
                                    {{category.CategoryName}}
                                </mat-panel-title>
                                <mat-panel-description *ngIf="!category.Expanded"
                                    style="margin-left: -4px;margin-right: -6px;">
                                    <mat-icon style="color: #FFFFFF;">keyboard_arrow_down</mat-icon>
                                </mat-panel-description>
                                <mat-panel-description *ngIf="category.Expanded"
                                    style="margin-left: -4px;margin-right: -6px;">
                                    <mat-icon style="color: #FFFFFF;">keyboard_arrow_up</mat-icon>
                                </mat-panel-description>
                            </mat-expansion-panel-header>
```

Comment: are u asking about tooltip we get while hovering over any button or text?

Comment: please add your code and create a code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;

  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
</style>
<body style="text-align:center;">

<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">Hover over me toolTip using Css
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>

<p title="someText">This is a paragraph with Tooltip set using Title attribute.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

There can be two different ways of creating 'tooltip'

1. by CSS
2. by using attribute called title.

the above example will show you both the usage and for more details and customization you can visit [here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_tooltip.asp).

Comment: i have already suggested that answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you. thanks

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  /* Position the tooltip */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}

.tooltip button:hover+.tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="tooltip"> <button>Tooltip Button</button>
  <span class="tooltiptext">Tooltip text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this one

```css
   .hoverer {
 position: relative;
 margin-top: 30px;
}
.hoverer:hover::after {
 content: attr(hover-text);
 position: absolute;
 top: -25px;
 left: 0;
 font-size: 13px;
 border: 1px solid #333333;
 padding: 2px 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #effdfe, #a2ecf5);
}
```

```html
<p class="hoverer" hover-text="hello i am hovered text">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab a sint cumque, minus impedit. Earum, debitis quidem natus dolores aliquid libero ipsum doloremque eum repellendus voluptate blanditiis, omnis molestias cumque!
 </p>
```

Comment: I don't think this the answer to the question. The OP needs a tooltip.

Comment: mat-tooltip might be good option to use.